# When should I create a new DbContext()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am currently using a `DbContext` similar to this:

```
namespace Models
{
    public class ContextDB: DbContext
    {
              
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }

        public ContextDB()
        {
            
        }
    }
}
```

I am then using the following line at the top of **ALL** my controllers that need access to the database. Im also using it in my UserRepository Class which contains all methods relating to the user (such as getting the active user, checking what roles he has, etc..):

```
ContextDB _db = new ContextDB();
```

Thinking about this, there are occasions when one visitor can have multiple DbContexts active, for instance if it is visiting a controller that uses the UserRepository, which might not be the best of ideas.

When should I make a new DbContext? Alternatively, should I have one global context that is passed around and reused in all places? Would that cause a performance hit? Suggestions of alternative ways of doing this are also welcome.

Comment: In this case I'd use dependency injection (e.g. Ninject), so it would create one `DbContext` per request. I'd also create service layer. Check [this SO question & answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7408973/mvc-3-how-to-implement-a-service-layer-do-i-need-repositories)

Comment: For non-ASP cases or trying to use singleton  see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871666/linq-and-datacontext (which was suggested as duplicate)

Answer (score 90, accepted):

I use a base controller that exposes a `DataBase` property that derived controllers can access.

```
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
{
    public BaseController()
    {
        Database = new DatabaseContext();
    }

    protected DatabaseContext Database { get; set; }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        Database.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

All of the controllers in my application derive from `BaseController` and are used like this:

```
public class UserController : BaseController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(Database.Users.OrderBy(p => p.Name).ToList());
    }
}
```

Now to answer your questions:

> When should I make a new DbContext / should I have one global context
>   that I pass around?

The context should be created per request. Create the context, do what you need to do with it then get rid of it. With the base class solution I use you only have to worry about using the context.

Do not try and have a global context (this is not how web applications work).

> Can I have one global Context that I reuse in all places?

No, if you keep a context around it will keep track of all the updates, additions, deletes etc and this will slow your application down and may even cause some pretty subtle bugs to appear in your application.

You should probably chose to either expose your repository **or** your Context to your controller but not both. Having two contexts being access from the same method is going to lead to bugs if they both have different ideas about the current state of the application.

Personally, I prefer to expose `DbContext` directly as most repository examples I have seen simply end up as thin wrappers around `DbContext` anyway.

> Does this cause a performance hit?

The first time a `DbContext` is created is pretty expensive but once this has been done a lot of the information is cached so that subsequent instantiations are a lot quicker. you are more likely to see performance problems from keeping a context around than you are from instantiating one each time you need access to your database.

> How is everyone else doing this?

It depends.

Some people prefer to use a dependency injection framework to pass a concrete instance of their context to their controller when it is created. Both options are fine. Mine is more suitable for a small scale application where you know the specific database being used isn't going to change.

some may argue that you *can't* know this and that is why the dependency injection method is better as it makes your application more resilient to change. My opinion on this is that it probably won't change (SQL server & Entity Framework are hardly obscure) and that my time is best spent writing the code that is specific to my application.

Comment: I have nothing to add to this, other than it's nice to see some of my own preferences reflected in other people's posts.  I've never really understood repository examples that result in yet another layer added onto a DbContext, without really adding anything, and I'm a fan of creating a base class that exposes a protected DbContext.

Comment: Wanted to add that this answer is great but now out of date with the release of EF6 which automatically disposes of the context after each use. As such there are scenarios where creating a per session (global) context is okay. If you are using EF6 for connectivity to Stored Procedures and data locking is not an issue then it is possibly ideal to create the context once in a base controller and have all the controllers that required database access inherit from the base. The most correct answer is you need to keep abreast of the technology and apply the correct pattern for your architecture.

Comment: What if i want to call some models method from controller action that use DbContext? How can i pass it to models method?

Comment: Then you are doing database queryies and business logic in the controller where they don't belong. You should create a service that is called from your controller. I.e. your UserController calls a method in your UserService.

Comment: @Fred, yes, and how do i pass DbContext to UserService, by simple parameter to function or no?

Comment: @RMazitov, you don't. The controller shouldn't be aware of any DbContext. You should initialize the DbContext in the UserService (or in a layer below such as the UserManager if you have that).

Comment: Theoretically, we're supposed to use the repository pattern to prevent brittleness in the unlikely event that we change our data storage mechanism and therefore our data access code.

Comment: You are basically creating the db context once per request and then sharing it here. How is that different from a "global context" or "keeping a context around"?

Comment: Two things about this answer. Having the context exposed as a property in this manner makes an assumption about the use of the class (that only one method will be called). If I instantiate the class manually, however, I could end up with a situation where I call more than one method which may lead to an uncertainty of the state of the context. Also, this is not testable as it has a hard dependency on the context (hence the need for interfaces and/or wrappers, even if they are thin).

Answer (score 15):

I try to answer out of my own experience.

**1. When should I make a new DbContext / should I have one global context that I pass around?**

The Context should be injected by the dependency-injection and should not be instantiated by yourself. Best-Practice is to have it created as a scoped service by the dependency-injection. (See my answer to Question 4)

Please also consider using a proper layered application structure like Controller > BusinessLogic > Repository. In this case it would not be the case that your controller receives the db-context but the repository instead. Getting injected / instantiating a db-context in a controller tells me that your application architecture mixes many responsibilities in one place, which - under any circumstances - I cannot recommend.

**2. Can i have one global Context that I reuse in all places?**

Yes you **can** have but the question should be "**Should** I have..." -> NO. The Context is meant to be used per request to change your repository and then its away again.

**3. Does this cause a performance hit?**

Yes it does because the DBContext is simply not made for being global. It stores all the data that has been entered or queried into it until it is destroyed. That means a global context will get larger and larger, operations on it will get slower and slower until you will get an out of memory exceptions or you die of age because it all slowed to a crawl.

You will also get exceptions and many errors when multiple threads access the same context at once.

**4. How is everyone else doing this?**

DBContext injected through dependency-injection by a factory; scoped:

```
services.AddDbContext<UserDbContext>(o => o.UseSqlServer(this.settings.DatabaseOptions.UserDBConnectionString));
```

I hope my answers where of help.

Comment: What if I want to use the DBContext in the Startup.cs in the ConfigureServices method itself ? 
I have a OICD Middleware, where I need to access the DB, but I cannot access the DBContext or i don't know how?

Comment: In the configureServices method, your DBContext is likely unavailable because you configured it there. The ServiceProvider from which you actually get your DBContext at runtime will first be available in the Configure() (Not "ConfigureServices"!) method. There, you can request the Context using the ApplicationBuilder by typing  "app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<MyDbContext>();" (Replace MyDbContext with the classname of your own context).

Comment: If Controllers get a Repository injected, how do they (Controllers) save changes? Let's say I'm sending a POST request to insert something in the database, the controller handles the request, uses the repository to add the newly created objected .. then what? Who persist the changes?

Comment: @MMalke The Repository does that. It typically has a function "SaveData(Data myData)"   and then the Repository creates an instance of its Entity-Framework sibling for the Data-Class, adds it to the according dbset in the dbcontext and then it calls SaveChanges().

The only thing the controller does is call the Repository.SaveData(myData) function.

Answer (score 4):

You should dispose the context immediately after each Save() operation. Otherwise each subsequent Save will take longer. I had an project that created and saved complex database entities in a cycle. To my surprise, the operation became three times faster after I moved

```
using (var ctx = new MyContext()){...}
```

inside the cycle.

Answer (score 3):

In performance point of view, `DbContext` should be created `just` when it is actually needed, For example when you need to have list of users inside your business layer,you create an instance form your DbContext and **`immediately dispose`** it when your work is done

```
using (var context=new DbContext())
{
    var users=context.Users.Where(x=>x.ClassId==4).ToList();
}
```

`context` instance will be disposed after leaving `Using` Block.

But what would happen if you do not dispose it immediately?
`DbContext` is a cache in the essence and the more you make query the more memory blocks will be occupied.
It will be much more noticeable in case of **`concurrent requests`** flooding towards your application, in this case,each millisecond that you are occupying a memory block would be of the essence, let alone a second.
the more you postpone disposing unnecessary objects the more your application is closed to crash!

Of course in some cases you need to preserve your `DbContext` instance and use it in another part of your code but in the same **`Request Context`**.

I refer you to the following link to get more info regarding managing `DbContext`:
[dbcontext Scope](https://mehdi.me/ambient-dbcontext-in-ef6/)

Answer (score 0):

Right now I am trying this approach, which avoids instantiating the context when you call actions that don't use it.

```
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
{
    public BaseController() { }

    private DatabaseContext _database;
    protected DatabaseContext Database
    {
        get
        {
            if (_database == null)
                _database = new DatabaseContext();
            return _database;
        }
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (_database != null)
            _database.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

Comment: While there is nothing wrong with your approach I believe that an Entity Framework context will do everything in a lazy fashion and no real work is performed until you actually access the database. So the overhead of creating an EF context should be very small.

Comment: I did some research and it seems that's correct. I did some simple test by comparing what `GC.GetTotalMemory()` returned (not perfect but it's what I found) and the difference was never greater than 8Kb.

Answer (score -1):

This is obviously an older question but if your using DI you can do something like this and scope all your objects for the lifetime of the request

```
 public class UnitOfWorkAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            var context = IoC.CurrentNestedContainer.GetInstance<DatabaseContext>();
            context.BeginTransaction();
        }

        public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionContext)
        {
            var context = IoC.CurrentNestedContainer.GetInstance<DatabaseContext>();
            context.CloseTransaction(actionContext.Exception);
        }
    }
```