# Duplicate DataType is being created on every Product Creation

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a Product Model that allows users to define their own Custom fields for their Product.  This is accomplished by have 3 tables/models.  The `Product` model which contains an IEnumerable enumeration of `CustomProductProperty` models. in each `CustomProductPropertyModel` is a foreign key to a `DataType` model. This `DataType` model is where users define what fields are available.

The problem I am having is that everytime a user creates a new Product, a new set of `DataType` is created.  How do I handle the data so that The `CustomProductProperty` points to an existing `DataType` and not creating a new one?

```
[Table("Product")]
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public int ProductTypeID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Product Name")]
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ProductTypeID")]
    [Display(Name = "Product Type")]
    public virtual ProductType ProductType { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CustomProductProperty> CustomProperties { get; set; } 
}

[Table("CustomProductProperty")]
public class CustomProductProperty
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int CustomPropertyID { get; set; }

    public int CustomDataTypeID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CustomDataTypeID")]
    public CustomDataType DataType { get; set; }

    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ProductID")]
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }

    public string PropertyValue { get; set; }
}

[Table("CustomDataType")]
public class CustomDataType
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int CustomTypeID { get; set; }
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }
    public CustomDataTypes DataType { get; set; }
    public int ModuleID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ModuleID")]
    public Module Module { get; set; }
}
```

In the creation form I included a `@Html.HiddenFor()` for `DataType.CustomTypeID` and when debugging, it is included but when I add to my dbcontext, it creates a brand new `DataType`

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Products.Add(productViewModel.Product);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

EDIT: The form for creating a product is as follows.

```
<table class="basic_info_tbl">
    <tr>
        <th>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Product.ProductName):</th>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Product.ProductName) </td>
        <th>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Product.ProductType):</th>
        <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Product.ProductTypeID, Model.ProductTypes)</td>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Product.CustomProperties)
    </tr>
</table>
```

With the Editor Template:

```
<tr>
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.DataType.CustomTypeID)
    <th>@Model.DataType.PropertyName</th>
    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PropertyValue)</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Your datatype has to be attached to the context, otherwise a new one will be created.

Comment: How do I go about doing that?

Comment: for example: `DataType dt = new DataType { CustomTypeID = someDataFromTheModel}; context.Set<DataType>().Attach(dt);`. This suposes that CustomTypeID is the primary key for DataType.

Comment: And if I have an `ICollection<>` Collection of a Model that contains DataType, do I just run that in a `foreach` loop?

Comment: yes you have to, or you may try to attach an entity graph comprising the ICollection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Lerman & Miller's book *DbContext*:

> adding the root of a graph will cause every entity in
>   the graph to be registered with the context as a new entity. This behavior is the same
>   if you use `DbSet.Add` or change the `State` property for an entity to `Added`. Once all the
>   entities are tracked by the state manager, you can *then work your way around the graph,
>   specifying the correct state for each entity.*

(my emphasis)

So after `db.Products.Add(productViewModel.Product)` also the `CustomDataType` objects in the object graph are `Added`.

After the `Add()` you should loop through the object graph

```
foreach (var dt in productViewModel.Product.CustomProperties
                                   .Select(x => x.DataType).ToList())
{
    Entry(dt).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
}
```

Comment: I get an error when I tried implementing this `An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key.`  Doing some research it says I need to check if its already being tracked and use `EntityState.Modified` if it is? but I don't want that data to accidentally change.

Comment: Where do you get the exception? This should be possible. Are there more things happening that you left out for brevity?

Comment: Im getting the exception at `Entry(dt).State = EntityState.Unchanged;` I havent left anything else out. its basically those 3 models in the view.

Comment: I added the Form just in case it may help.

Comment: This indicates that somehow you load the `CustomDataType`s before you change the state.

Comment: Would it have been loaded during the GET request? Because I don't see anywhere that I loaded `CustomDataType`s before changing the state during the POST action.

Comment: That depends on the lifespan of `db`. I'd expect `db` to live for one request.

Comment: Hm, well it lives in the ProductController `private readonly DatabaseEntries db = new DatabaseEntries();` I was told that creating a new dbContext everytime would be costly.

Comment: It is not that costly. It is optimized for quick instantiation. But still... with MVC normally the controller factory creates a controller per request so you should have a new db. Could you try what happens if you create a new db in the action method?

Comment: Oh that works now, Thanks for pointing that out. that being said, [This Stackoverflow Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13551100/when-should-i-create-a-new-dbcontext) says good practice is to create a `BaseController`, how would that help with the issue I'm facing?

Comment: Well, you've just witnessed a side-effect of a context with a "long" lifespan. I nearly always make sure I have a context per request. Your issue would be much harder to tackle with an unknown number of objects loaded before the action method runs.