# Why instantiate new DbContext for each step of test

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

In the Entity Framework Core documentation on [Testing with SQLite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/sqlite), the sample code instantiates a new `DbContext` for each step of a test. Is there a reason for doing this?

```
    // Copied from the docs:
    [Fact]
    public void Add_writes_to_database()
    {
        // In-memory database only exists while the connection is open
        var connection = new SqliteConnection("DataSource=:memory:");
        connection.Open();

        try
        {
            var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<BloggingContext>()
                .UseSqlite(connection)
                .Options;

            // Create the schema in the database
            using (var context = new BloggingContext(options))
            {
                context.Database.EnsureCreated();
            }

            // Run the test against one instance of the context
            using (var context = new BloggingContext(options))
            {
                var service = new BlogService(context);
                service.Add("http://sample.com");
                context.SaveChanges();
            }

            // Use a separate instance of the context to verify correct data was saved to database
            using (var context = new BloggingContext(options))
            {
                Assert.Equal(1, context.Blogs.Count());
                Assert.Equal("http://sample.com", context.Blogs.Single().Url);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }

    // Why not do this instead:
    [Fact]
    public void Add_writes_to_database()
    {
        // In-memory database only exists while the connection is open
        var connection = new SqliteConnection("DataSource=:memory:");
        connection.Open();

        try
        {
            var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<BloggingContext>()
                .UseSqlite(connection)
                .Options;

            // Create the schema in the database
            using (var context = new BloggingContext(options))
            {
                context.Database.EnsureCreated();

                var service = new BlogService(context);
                service.Add("http://sample.com");
                context.SaveChanges();

                Assert.Equal(1, context.Blogs.Count());
                Assert.Equal("http://sample.com", context.Blogs.Single().Url);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
```

Why not instantiate the context once, and use that instance throughout the entire test method, as shown in the second code sample?

Comment: If your test connects to a database, then it's not a unit test...it's an _integration test_.

Comment: Good point, I edited the title

Comment: Actually comments from third creation tell about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because [that's how contexts should be used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13551100/). They should be created per request and disposed of.

One *practical* reason is to ensure that you're going back to the data source each time instead of just looking at state within the context.